# Getting total quantity of specific product ordered between two dates

Tags: admin, orders, magento-1.6, collection-filtering

I have a requirement to get the total number of ordered items for a specific product ID during a specific time period.

I.e. - Total number of Product 123 ordered between 1st June 2014 and 30st June 2014.

I'm looking for the best way to do this.

Initially, I looked at `reports/product_collection` but it seems slow compared to `sales/order_item_collection` from tests I've carried out (simple execution time).

The code I have at the moment is (with $week being a period to search through, and $row being a reference to an internal table where product_id is stored):

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => $row->getProductId()))
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'created_at', array("gt" => array(
            $week["from"]
         )
         )
    )
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'created_at', array("lt" => array(
             $week["to"]
         )
         )
    );
```

However, then I have to loop through the resulting collection, adding the quantities together to get the figure I want.

```
 $qtySold = 0;
 foreach($collection as $orderItem) {
     $qtySold += $orderItem->getQtyOrdered();
 }
```

I *feel* like I should be able to do this in the original collection call by using something like `addExpressionAttributeToSelect` (but this doesn't work on the `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Item_Collection` object).

Any thoughts on the best, most Magento (currently the store is running 1.6) way to do this?  It's worth pointing out (I guess) that the PHP counter works, but it just doesn't feel right, especially as the collection could have thousands of orders in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling over this in the future, I've gone for the following code as the most (to me) sensible version:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection');
$collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->columns(array('SUM(qty_ordered) as order_quantity'))
    ->where(sprintf("product_id = %s", $row->getProductId()))
    ->where(sprintf('created_at > "%s" AND created_at < "%s"', $week["from"], $week["to"]));
```

I'm yet to figure out if it would be quicker to grab all my date ranges at once and work through them in PHP, or if it's quicker like this creating a separate block for each week.

Comment: Good Works ...i  give  u upvote

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would also serve what you need. Though you may have missed a group by on your select.

```
$sum = new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM(%s)', 'qty_ordered'));
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('product_id')
    ->addExpressionFieldToSelect('summed_qty_ordered', $sum, 'qty_ordered')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => $row->getProductId()))
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'created_at', array("gt" => array(
            $week['from']
        )
        )
    )
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'created_at', array("lt" => array(
            $week['to']
        )
        )
    );
```

The line to add the sum is a bit anouying because `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql` has some nice default getting LENGTH or CONACT but has now SUM. But the code is the same as in the class.

Comment: I don't think I need to group by as I'm only searching on one product.  Going to benchmark against reversing my query and selecting everything from order_item_collection and then filtering to see (at which point I'll need to group by product id).  Will drop your code in and see if it is any quicker :)

Comment: sounds good. I have no idea if my code is quicker, it would be interesting to see. If you add the group though then you will get all entries for that product already summed and so you should save some time. Unless I have misunderstood what you are aiming to achieve here.